# Faster/cleaner way to calculate width/Left of textbox depending on how many are displayed

Tags: vb.net, math, textbox, positioning, activereports

Hey all i am currently looking for a way to calculate the width & left position of MAX 12 txtboxes on my report form. The height will always be **0.206** as well as top will always be **0**.

This is what the code looks like with 12 (max) txtboxes:

```
txtData1.Width = 0.7
txtData1.Left = 0

txtData2.Width = 0.7
txtData2.Left = 0.708

txtData3.Width = 0.7
txtData3.Left = 1.416

txtData4.Width = 0.7
txtData4.Left = 2.124

txtData5.Width = 0.7
txtData5.Left = 2.832

txtData6.Width = 0.7
txtData6.Left = 3.54

txtData7.Width = 0.7
txtData7.Left = 4.248

txtData8.Width = 0.7
txtData8.Left = 4.956

txtData9.Width = 0.7
txtData9.Left = 5.664

txtData10.Width = 0.7
txtData10.Left = 6.372

txtData11.Width = 0.7
txtData11.Left = 7.08

txtData12.Width = 0.7
txtData12.Left = 7.788
```

According to my calculations (which i love math...math just doesn't love me :o)) the total width would be **8.4 in** and the total left would be **7.788 in**. The sheet is 8.5 in wide (landscape view).

[image: layout]

So now the hard part comes into play. For 11 boxes, the width would go up a little and the left position would also go up to accommodation the extra space not having the 12th box anymore.

I am trying to find a nice way of doing this with minimal code since i know i can do the same as above for each level (12 to 2 textboxes) but that would be a lot of code.

So any help with calculating the remaining 11-2 txtboxes would be a big help! :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but what I am gathering is that you always want the textboxes to completely fill up the 8.5 inches.

If that is the case, I would do something as follows:

```
    Dim NumberOfBoxes As Integer = 11 ' Number of textboxes you'll have next to each other
    Dim AssignedWidthPerBox As Double = 8.5 / NumberOfBoxes
    Dim CurrentLeft As Double = 0   ' How Far left you are on your form - Increment this by AssignedWidthPerBox for each textbox
```

Then you assign the Textbox properties eaither through a loop (preferred) or by hand as follows:

```
    txtData1.Width = AssignedWidthPerBox
    txtData1.Left = CurrentLeft
    CurrentLeft += AssignedWidthPerBox
```

Hope this helps